# Admob Interstital Ads are not showing in Xamarin Forms Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, admob, interstitial

i am integrating google interstital ads admob in my xamarin forms application currently testing ads on android platform but the problem is that test ads are working fine but when i replace test unit ids with real unit ids then the ad is not showing

**here is my interface**

```
public  interface IAdInterstitial
{
    void ShowAd();
    void LoadInterstitialAd();
}
```

**here is android custom renderer With Test Interstital Ad ID**

```
public class AdInterstitial_Droid : IAdInterstitial
{
    InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
    public static bool isadLoaded = false;
    public AdInterstitial_Droid()
    {
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(Android.App.Application.Context);
        interstitialAd.AdListener = new MyAdListener(() =>
        {

        });

        // TODO: change this id to your admob id  
        interstitialAd.AdUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
        LoadAd();
    }

   public void LoadAd()
    {
        var requestbuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        interstitialAd.LoadAd(requestbuilder.Build());
    }

    public void ShowAd()
    {
        if (interstitialAd.IsLoaded)
        {
            interstitialAd.Show();
        }



        LoadAd();
    }

    public void LoadInterstitialAd()
    {
        var requestbuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        interstitialAd.LoadAd(requestbuilder.Build());
    }
}
```

**Function which shows my Interstital Ad**

```
private  void fullscreenad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DependencyService.Get<IAdInterstitial>().ShowAd();
    }
```

the above id is test id which is working fine but if i replace that test id with original id then ads are not showing

Answer (score 0):

If you have recently created an AD unit ID(in 24 hours), it may take some time and several AD requests to build up AD resources. Because of this, you may not immediately see the actual presentation. You can use the test unitID. Please note that the test AD runs through the same channels as the actual AD. If the test AD returns, your application is communicating correctly with the network.

If your issue  persists even if after 24 hours.You can check for more specific causes from the [google support](https://support.google.com/admob/troubleshooter/9092685)